# WPF/XAML padding property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to quick discover what is the base ancestor where 'padding' property is first defined/declared

Is there any quick way to discover where a member was first declared

Comment: Yes. Right click on the member in a C# file and select "Go to Definition". You could also search Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Padding` property, unlike `Margin`, has no common root implementation, instead it is separately introduced in multiple controls.

You can identify inherited properties in MSDN by the *"Inherited from [...]"* description in the class overview.

See also: [Understanding the Padding Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms751709(v=vs.110).aspx#Understanding%20the%20Padding%20Property) which mentions some `Padding` base classes.